# Make a loop run in background C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a loop to check for a debugger every 3 seconds or so and I know I need multithreading but I need an example or something since I'm really new to C++

I can't just loop it normally because then the rest of my code wont run.

```
void loop() {
    for (;;) {
        if (IsDebuggerPresent())
        {
            exit(1);
        }
        if (TRUE == CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(GetCurrentProcess(), &bDebuggerPresent) &&
            TRUE == bDebuggerPresent)
        {
            exit(2);
        }
        
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(loop); //activates loop
    if (t1.joinable()) {
        t1.join();
        t1.detach();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not so bad if you insert the main body of your program before the _if_ statement.  The join stuff is just cleanup to happen before your process exits.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't join your thread, if you want to continue execution on the spawning thread.

Comment: Pass code right after `std::thread t1(loop);`, not after the if statement, and other thing is that your thread will never join because it is infinite.

Comment: `TRUE == blah` is really ugly. Just the function call should suffice.

Comment: Yeah, don't use Yoda conditionals (get lose the habit they work-around), and use proper `true` and `false` rather than old C macros... but only if needed, which they aren't here as said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the rest of my code wont run.

See below.

```
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(loop); // activates loop

    // PUT YOUR CODE HERE.

    if (t1.joinable()) {  // shuts down loop
        t1.join();        // join OR detach.  Not both.
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe remove the `detach` after `join`, or is it doing anything useful I am not aware of?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I am very confident that you are correct.